# day of month and month identity from day of year

Tags: php, date

eg.

let say it is the 326 day of the year.

you want to be able to get the month and the day of the month eg. Oct 23 etc.

what is the formula. how do i achieve this in php.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Please provide more details and a clearer question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$d = date('m Y', strtotime($year . '-01-01'));
$d->add(new DateInterval('P' . $day_of_year . 'D'));
echo $d->month . ' ' . $d->mday; // same as `echo $date->format('F j')`, or "October 23"
```

See [PHP DateTime::add reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
date('m Y', strtotime($year . '-01-01 +' . ($day_of_year - 1) . 'days');
```

will get you a string containing the month and the year.

Answer (score -1):

take a look at the php date manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php
echo date('d-m'); //echoes 16-08
?>
```